# Is it possible to merge two separate android studio apps as one?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 separate android studio projects, the first one is a chatting app that i developed and the second one is a shopping app that my friend developed.
Now i want to create a button on the home screen that says "SHOP" and whenever it' s clicked i want the user to be taken to the shopping activity. The problem is i don't know if it' s possible to do that.

Comment: Its possible.  You can have as many launcher activities in an app as you want, each of which will get a separate icon in the apps list and can be made home screen icons.  Or you could go with a widget instead.  It all depends on which way you want to do it.  Of course the user would need to set that up, as an app can't add itself to the home screen.

Comment: Strictly answering your question: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: It's possible to use an `Intent` to [open another app](https://programmer.ink/think/how-to-start-the-activity-of-another-app-from-one-app.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a button first do the following

1. Open you Home Activity XMl fle in android studio and add button widget like below

   <Button
   android:text="SHOP"
   android:background="#009688"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:layout_height="51dp"
   android:id="@+id/shop"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:paddingRight="5dp"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
   tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
   / >

note: you can tweak the button styles to your taste

2. Then go to you Java home activity and bind the button widget to enable you call
   onClickListener() method like below

   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shop);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
   //here intent is used to open the new activity
   Intent intent = new Intent(homeScreenActivity.this, ShoppingActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   }
   });

You can also read about intent using the link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent